# Language Pack Dubai

Tags: magento, arabic, language-packs

I have to create a Magento website for Dubai and I'm looking for a language pack to start the project and avoid too much work !
I found only for locale ar_SA. But it seems that it's not the good dialect.
Do you know where find a language pack for Dubaï please ?
Or maybe, you have this pack ?

Thank for very much for your help !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Also, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You are right ! thk